# How to revert a file to previous revision and commit it in new revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

So i have single file in revision 110 which i want to revert to revision 109, make some changes in other files and commit everything as revision 111, how can i do that ?

Comment: Why don't copy the file in rev 109, update to 110, paste the file and do the changes and commit to 111?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an explanation in the documentation: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html

Answer (score 0):

You simply right-click the file you want to revert and use `TortoiseSVN -> Revert` to revert that file. Then you can make changes to the other files and commit everything. But I think you won't be on Revision `111` then. If that's what you need to achieve you should use Narmer's solution in the comment.